# Spark/Yarn: File does not exist on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have a Hadoop/Yarn cluster setup on AWS, I have one master and 3 slaves. I have verified I have 3 live nodes running on port 50070 and 8088. I tested a spark job in client deploy-mode, everything works fine.

When I try to spark-submit a job using `./spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster ip.py`. I'm getting the following error.

> Diagnostics: File does not exist:
>   hdfs://ec2-54-153-50-11.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/user/ubuntu/.sparkStaging/application_1495996836198_0003/__spark_libs__1200479165381142167.zip
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:
>   hdfs://ec2-54-153-50-11.us-west
>   1.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/user/ubuntu/.sparkStaging/application_1495996836198_0003/__spark_libs__1200479165381142167.zip

```
17/05/28 18:58:32 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/05/28 18:58:33 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ec2-54-153-50-11.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/172.31.5.235:8032
17/05/28 18:58:34 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 3 NodeManagers
17/05/28 18:58:34 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (8192 MB per container)
17/05/28 18:58:34 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 1408 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
17/05/28 18:58:34 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
17/05/28 18:58:34 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
17/05/28 18:58:34 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
17/05/28 18:58:36 WARN yarn.Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
17/05/28 18:58:41 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-fbd6d435-9abe-4396-838e-60f19bc2dc14/__spark_libs__1200479165381142167.zip -> hdfs://ec2-54-153-50-11.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/user/ubuntu/.sparkStaging/application_1495996836198_0003/__spark_libs__1200479165381142167.zip
17/05/28 18:58:45 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/ubuntu/ip.py -> hdfs://ec2-54-153-50-11.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/user/ubuntu/.sparkStaging/application_1495996836198_0003/ip.py
17/05/28 18:58:45 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/ubuntu/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://ec2-54-153-50-11.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/user/ubuntu/.sparkStaging/application_1495996836198_0003/pyspark.zip
17/05/28 18:58:45 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/ubuntu/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip -> hdfs://ec2-54-153-50-11.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/user/ubuntu/.sparkStaging/application_1495996836198_0003/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip
17/05/28 18:58:45 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-fbd6d435-9abe-4396-838e-60f19bc2dc14/__spark_conf__7895841687984145748.zip -> hdfs://ec2-54-153-50-11.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/user/ubuntu/.sparkStaging/application_1495996836198_0003/__spark_conf__.zip
17/05/28 18:58:46 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ubuntu
17/05/28 18:58:46 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ubuntu
17/05/28 18:58:46 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
17/05/28 18:58:46 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
17/05/28 18:58:46 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(ubuntu); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(ubuntu); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/05/28 18:58:46 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application application_1495996836198_0003 to ResourceManager
17/05/28 18:58:46 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1495996836198_0003
17/05/28 18:58:47 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/28 18:58:47 INFO yarn.Client:
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1495997926073
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://ec2-54-153-50-11.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8088/proxy/application_1495996836198_0003/
     user: ubuntu
17/05/28 18:58:48 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/28 18:58:49 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/28 18:58:50 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/28 18:58:51 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/28 18:58:52 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/28 18:58:53 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/28 18:58:54 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/28 18:58:55 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/28 18:58:56 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/28 18:58:57 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/28 18:58:58 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/28 18:58:59 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/28 18:59:00 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/28 18:59:01 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/28 18:59:02 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1495996836198_0003 (state: FAILED)
17/05/28 18:59:02 INFO yarn.Client:
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1495996836198_0003 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1495996836198_0003_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://ec2-54-153-50-11.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1495996836198_0003Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: File does not exist: hdfs://ec2-54-153-50-11.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/user/ubuntu/.sparkStaging/application_1495996836198_0003/__spark_libs__1200479165381142167.zip
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://ec2-54-153-50-11.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/user/ubuntu/.sparkStaging/application_1495996836198_0003/__spark_libs__1200479165381142167.zip
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1495997926073
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://ec2-54-153-50-11.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1495996836198_0003
     user: ubuntu
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1495996836198_0003 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1226)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
17/05/28 18:59:02 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/05/28 18:59:02 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-fbd6d435-9abe-4396-838e-60f19bc2dc14
ubuntu@ip-172-31-5-235:~$
```

Comment: Have you run this ip.py in client deploy mode? How about standalone? Could you share some version or gist of the code? Have other Python/Scala/java spark apps run successfully against this cluster in the same manner? I presume your shell is the master, please correct if I'm wrong there. Also, check permissions on HDFS to be sure you have perms to write to that directory

Comment: In client deploy mode, everything runs fine.

Comment: Have you tried to test connectivity to HDFS port 9000 from each of your slaves?

Answer (score 11):

I was setting the master to local (`.setMaster('local')`) in my source file. After I remove this, everything works fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was banging my head for hours. It could've just said this in error.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I tried the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44233328/2507197) of removing the `setMaster('local')` in the source, however the error did not go away.

What finally solved my problem was actually quite simple: the sparkcontext [needed to be initialized First](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10795#comment-15180011) (even before non-spark related variables).

### Solution

From the post mentioned above, here is a python example. The same logic worked for me in scala

> Hi there, If i follow your suggestions, it works.
>
> Our code was like that :
>
> ```
> Import numpy as np 
> Import SparkContext 
> foo = np.genfromtext(xxxxx) 
> sc=SparkContext(...)
> #compute
> ```
>
> ===> It fails ...
>
> ```
> Import numpy as np 
> Import SparkContext 
> sc=SparkContext(...) 
> foo = np.genfromtext(xxxxx)
> #compute
> ```
>
> ===> It works perfectly ...

**Note** I also removed the `setMaster('local')`, because it makes sense that would interfere too.