# spark-submit fails giving FileNotFoundException

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am using spark 1.6. Below is the spark-submit command I am executing. Variables prefixed with '$' are dynamic variables.

```
spark-submit --queue "queue1" --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:./conf/log4j.properties -Dspark.yarn.keytab=$KEYTAB -Dspark.yarn.principal=$PRINCIPAL -Dkeytab=$KEYTAB -Dprincipal=$PRINCIPAL" --conf spark.yarn.am.cores=$am_cores --conf spark.yarn.am.memory="$am_memory" --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=$executor_memoryOverhead --conf spark.yarn.principal=$PRINCIPAL --conf spark.yarn.keytab=$KEYTAB  --conf spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false --conf spark.ui.enabled=true --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/conf/ --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/conf/ --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=$shuffle_partitions --name $APPNAME --master yarn --num-executors $num_executors --executor-memory $executor_memory --executor-cores $executor_cores --driver-memory $driver_memory --deploy-mode cluster --principal $PRINCIPAL --keytab $KEYTAB --files ./conf/log4j.properties --jars $APPSCALALIBJARFILES --class $APPCLASS $APPLIB
```

I am running spark-submit job on yarn cluster during which it is uploading dependent jars in default HDFS staging directory  which is `/user/<user id>/.sparkStaging/<yarn applicationId>/*.jar`.

On verification during spark-submit job, I see that jar is getting uploaded but spark-submit is failing with below error - file owner and group belongs to the same id using which spark-submit is performed. I also tried using configuration parameter `spark.yarn.StagingDir` but even that didn't helped.

Your professional inputs will help in addressing this issue.

Error stack trace -

```
Diagnostics: File does not exist: hdfs://user/<user id>/.sparkStaging/<yarn application_id>/chill-java-0.5.0.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:

hdfs://user/<user id>/.sparkStaging/<yarn application_id>/chill-java-0.5.0.jar
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1257)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1249)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1249)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:251)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:357)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:356)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:60)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: 'I am running spark-submit job' please provide spark-submit with versions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark/Yarn: File does not exist on HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231261/spark-yarn-file-does-not-exist-on-hdfs)

Comment: added as an answer since spark-submit command was containing more words then it was allowing in commnet.

Comment: yes scenario or issue is same. But i am initializing sparkcontext first before any application logic.

Comment: are you using yarn or local ?

Comment: yarn in cluster mode